# How many layers your small REST system should have?

Tags: rest, architecture, layered

I am building simple REST deployable using Spring Boot. Decided to create it by using failing acceptance test first followed with TDD until its green.

My module is pretty simple, I have 3 API's:

1. Retrieving list of data from datastore.
2. Adds item to datastore.
3. Deletes item from datastore.

I feel like it is good idea to abstract datastore and have maybe backed by Map data structure for testing purposes and use it with either NoSQL or SQL db if I want to for deployments/releases and end to end testing.

On the service layer side I am unsure since it would just delegate call to repository with no logic.

So standard approach would be controller->service->repository. In my case service does not do much(possible some exception handling but not more) and I will end up with interface and implementation as an extra as well as few more lines of code. I fell like going for controller->repository solution in my situation but it is not a practice I have seen and not sure how others would see it.

What's the best way to implement this sort of system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I feel like it is good idea to abstract datastore

You are right. The abstraction is called 'Repository' in DDD (Domain Driven Design) for example.

> On the service layer side I am unsure since it would just delegate call to repository with no logic.

I'm pretty sure there are data that you want to validate. So you should have a layer in the middle (e.g. the domain layer) which will be in charge of this validation.

Even so, if you feel like your application is simple and doesn't require such layers, go without. You will have less supple design, but more simplicity at first. Be careful: while evolving your app, you could run into trouble.

Hope this will help.

Comment: If you use DDD and repositories etc., then there is no need for a service layer because you model will implement all domain logic, your controller all API/HTTP logic, and you can put transaction boundaries on repository layer. The service layer is usually some kind of 'transaction script' which you don't need if you have good object model (DDD).

Answer (score 1):

This is rather an opinion based question, but if you are asking whether a 3 layer architecture is a must, to that I say no. Be pragmatic, if you don' see a reason for a class/layer/module to exist, it does not need to exist.

A repository has a purpose (to store/retrieve), and the api layer has a purpose, to offer those things through HTTP.

Here is an article for building small services with the sparkframework: https://dzone.com/articles/building-simple-restful-api